# At simple_form, “Required: false” is not working

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form-for

I am building a form with name, email, phone and message inputs. The phone input is the only that I need to remain as not required, so I set like this:

`<%= f.input :phone, required: false, label: "Telefone", placeholder: "(XX) XXXXX-XXXX " %>`

And in the `simple_form initializer (config/initializers/simple_form.rb) set config.browser_validations = true`

The asterisk was removed, but I'm still getting and error saying the phone field is required. Any hints on how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please consider how to write a minimal complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  & https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), otherwise, it is often hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the rendered html to your post? Open the page with your browser, go to Developer Tools/Inspector and in the Elements tab look for the html generated by your code. Post it here so we can see what's actually being generated.

Meanwhile, try adding the `html` hash and setting required to false:

```
<%= f.input : phone, label: 'Telefone', placeholder: '(XX) XXXXX-XXXX', html: { required: false } %>
```

Comment: Please split your answer into a comment to ask for more info and keep the code as an answer.

Comment: Hi @Cahuê! Thanks for you help!

I've included the html hash but the issue persists. This is the html that's being generated:

```<div class="form-group tel optional page_phone form-group-invalid"><label class="tel optional" for="page_phone">Telefone</label><input class="form-control is-invalid string tel optional" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="(XX) XXXXX-XXXX " type="tel" value=" " name="page[phone]" id="page_phone"><div class="invalid-feedback">Phone can't be blank and Phone is not a number</div></div>```

Comment: Hey! It looks like the validations are being done in the model. Whatever model you are trying to use for this form, check its file and look for validations within the model!